# does the numbers of partitions of all joined tables affect the maximal executors?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL like

```
select ...
from A 
join B on A.k = B.k
join C on A.k = C.k
```

A has 2k partitions; B has 7 partitions; while C is not partitioned.

I set the maximal dynamic executor number to be 50. However, the application got < 20 executors. When two stages run in parallel, one stage uses 5 executors, while the other uses 6.

Should I increase the partition numbers of B and C to parallelize the query more?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, there is an impact due to uneven partitions and they are:
Less concurrency – You are not using advantages of parallelism. There could be worker nodes which are sitting ideal. Data skewing and improper resource utilization.
Your data might be skewed on one partition and hence your one worker might be doing more than other workers and hence resource issues might come at that worker.

Since there is a trade-off between partition count, they should be in right number otherwise task scheduling may take more time than actual execution time.
You should have usually between 100 and 10K partitions depending upon cluster size and data.

Lower bound – 2 X number of cores in cluster available to application
Upper bound – task should take 100+ ms time to execute.If it is taking less time than your partitioned data is too small and your application might be spending more time in scheduling the tasks.